# Space in scanf after format specifier vs space before format specifier ("%c " vs " %c")

Tags: c

I wanted to know the meaning of space after the format specifier in scanf. There are many posts related to space in scanf and most of them talk of the space before %c. In the below code, I have to enter second character for first scanf to return. Just entering enter key will not break the scanf. Because of this second character, second scanf for reading the string is also getting affected. 
Can I say that space after %c is for ignoring all white spaces entered after the character and wait until next character? But why "enter" key is not considered as a character itself?

```
char str[50];
char c;
printf("Enter the Character:");
scanf("%c ",&c);
printf("Char read is: %c",c);
printf("Enter the string:");
scanf("%s",str);
printf("%s", str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use trailing space after `"%c"` then `scanf` will need to find the next non-white-space to be able to return. If there is none then `scanf` will block for ever.

Comment: But why Enter key is not considered as non white space?

Comment: @Rajesh well, because [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) consider `'\n'` a [white-space character](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace)...